# Node.js on Raspberry Pi/Debian: setTimeout behavior is peculiar/unreliable

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

So I'm running OSMC on my Raspberry Pi device, which is essentially Debian + Kodi. I have a Node.js app running that tells Kodi (via its JSON-RPC API) to play some video at midnight. The scheduling is very basic: figure out the time of next midnight, subtract the current time, and you have the delay to pass to `setTimeout`.

Easy right? Except it doesn't work. When I came into the office next morning, no video was playing and according to the logs, the callback to `setTimeout` was never even called.

I did the obvious thing and set the Pi's system clock to 23:58 PM, started my program, waited two minutes and sure enough: the video started playing without a problem. It also works fine if the interval is not 1 day, but for example 10 minutes.

I then wrote the simplest Node.js program to schedule some logs at increasing time intervals (1s, 1m, 5m, 1h, 8h and 24h); it also prints the current time every hour:

```
function log(format) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    console.log.apply(null, ['%s: ' + format, new Date()].concat(args));
}

function schedule(delay) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        log('callback called after %d ms', delay);
    }, delay);

    log('scheduled setTimeout(%d)', delay);
}

schedule(1000);
schedule(60 * 1000);
schedule(5 * 60 * 1000);
schedule(60 * 60 * 1000);
schedule(8 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
schedule(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

function logTime() {
    log('current time is %s', new Date());
}

logTime();
setInterval(logTime, 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

This is what its output was when I ran it in `screen`:

```
Mon Apr 25 2016 14:11:54 GMT+0200 (CEST): scheduled setTimeout(1000)
Mon Apr 25 2016 14:11:54 GMT+0200 (CEST): scheduled setTimeout(60000)
Mon Apr 25 2016 14:11:54 GMT+0200 (CEST): scheduled setTimeout(300000)
Mon Apr 25 2016 14:11:54 GMT+0200 (CEST): scheduled setTimeout(3600000)
Mon Apr 25 2016 14:11:54 GMT+0200 (CEST): scheduled setTimeout(28800000)
Mon Apr 25 2016 14:11:54 GMT+0200 (CEST): scheduled setTimeout(86400000)
Mon Apr 25 2016 14:11:54 GMT+0200 (CEST): current time is Mon Apr 25 2016 14:11:54 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Mon Apr 25 2016 14:11:55 GMT+0200 (CEST): callback called after 1000 ms
Mon Apr 25 2016 14:12:55 GMT+0200 (CEST): callback called after 60000 ms
Mon Apr 25 2016 14:16:55 GMT+0200 (CEST): callback called after 300000 ms
Mon Apr 25 2016 15:21:31 GMT+0200 (CEST): callback called after 3600000 ms
Mon Apr 25 2016 15:21:31 GMT+0200 (CEST): current time is Mon Apr 25 2016 15:21:31 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Mon Apr 25 2016 16:21:31 GMT+0200 (CEST): current time is Mon Apr 25 2016 16:21:31 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Tue Apr 26 2016 08:01:23 GMT+0200 (CEST): current time is Tue Apr 26 2016 08:01:23 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Tue Apr 26 2016 08:01:23 GMT+0200 (CEST): callback called after 28800000 ms
```

So the short intervals worked as expected, but both the 1 hour callback and the 8 hour callback *didn't even kick off until I actually went to check the output*. Also, most of the hourly logs are missing.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

I'm running Node.js v5.10.1 but v4.4.3 shows the same behavior.

Comment: Is there any sort of sleep mode or hibernation?

Comment: @BenFortune: you know, that actually makes sense. I read that the RPi doesn't support power management but maybe things have changed since the RPi 3. I'll look into it.

Comment: The RPi 3 still doesn't have any sort of power management, but OSMC might have some way of idling. Try looking at `journalctl -b` to see if there's any sort of idle management.

Comment: @BenFortune: Here's the output: http://pastebin.com/cexbTwv7 . I'm not sure what to look for really.

Comment: I found the issue on Node.js Github: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4262

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a known issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4262